# Error: HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument. when running firebase functions:config:set

Tags: typescript, firebase, terminal, stripe-payments, http-status-code-400

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@GaryHarrower/working-with-stripe-webhooks-firebase-cloud-functions-5366c206c6c). In it there is a step which states:

> Now we have our signing secret and our API key, let’s add them to our Firebase project as environment variables so we don’t need to check them in to any source control.

```
$ firebase functions:config:set \
    keys.webhooks="your_restricted_key" \
    keys.signing="your_signing_key"
```

So I set the restricted key as the TOKEN key of my webhook, and the signing key as my publishable key. I then try and run the code in the console (The command in code above).

**It fails, returning the following error:**

> Error: HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the forward slashes:

```
$ firebase functions:config:set 
    keys.webhooks="your_restricted_key" 
    keys.signing="your_signing_key"
```

Tell me if it doesn't work, thanks NCT 127