# What is my Stripe signing key and where can I find it?

Tags: typescript, firebase, terminal, stripe-payments

I'm following [this article](https://medium.com/@GaryHarrower/working-with-stripe-webhooks-firebase-cloud-functions-5366c206c6c). I am looking for my Stripe signing key, as needed here:

```
$ firebase functions:config:set \
   keys.webhooks="your_restricted_key" \
   keys.signing="your_signing_key" <--
```

At first I thought it was my publishing key, but after trying it I got the error in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66630900/error-http-error-400-request-contains-an-invalid-argument-when-running-fireb)

### **SOLUTION:**

Go to:

**Endpoints receiving events from your account**

at `dev/webhooks` on stripe console.

click into your webhook:

**it is under: `Signing secret`**

Comment: Did you set up your webhooks and everything as you can/have to set up your signing key within there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the webhook signing secret `whsec_123` on an individual webhook page when you click it from your dashboard [here](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks), which is used to [verify event signatures](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures).

Note that every configured endpoint has a unique key, even if pointing at the same URL. This is a common mistake. If, for example, you have a live & test endpoint pointed at the same URL, these will use distinct keys and you will need to distinguish the events for verifying the signature.

That said, the error you pointed to (invalid argument) appears unrelated to verifying signatures. You need to debug your handler to isolate what is causing the error and provide more detail here. What does your webhook handler code ook like? Where does the error come from? What is the input request type/body?